# Comparing 2 rows using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic

**Input**

```
aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd|5|5|4
aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd|10|10|1
wwwww|xxxxx|yyyyy|zzzzz|5|5|2
wwwww|xxxxx|yyyyy|zzzzz|10|10|2
```

**Output**

```
aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd|5|5|
wwwww|xxxxx|yyyyy|zzzzz|10|10|
```

**Used for index are:**

1st to 4th column(e.g. aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd)

The logic for the output are the following:

1. Compare last column of records with same index, the record with the higher last column value will be printed to the output.
2. Compare last column of records with same index, if they are equal, the record with the greater value for columns 5 and 6 will be printed to the output.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am thinking of using awk. I just have no idea how to compare rows with the same index in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it with `sort`ing accordingly and then picking the first entry for each group.

```
sort filename -t'|' -k1,4 -k7rn -k5,6rn | sort -t'|' -k1,4 -u
```

Result:

```
aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd|5|5|4
wwwww|xxxxx|yyyyy|zzzzz|10|10|2
```

---

What this does is

- `-t'|'` set the field delimiter to `|`
- `-k1,4` order by the first 4 fields
- `-k7rn` then by the seventh field in reverse and numeric comparison
- `-k5,6rn` then the same with the fifth and sixth field
- `|` pipe this to another sort
- `-k1,4 -u` **the `-u` stands for uniqueness of the first 4 fields**

So the whole operation is like ordering the file as you want it, so that your desired row is displayed first in groups of the first 4 fields. Then just grab the first row for each group.

Comment: Hi fancyPants. Thank you for your inputs. However, I am not looking to sort the rows with respect to their column. I would like to write the output of the said logic to another file.

Comment: @peon It does exactly that. The procedure as described here is for example often used in database queries, too, like `select price as max_price from products order by price desc limit 1;` Don't be confused because of the sorting. It's sorting only, so that it can select (in the second sort with the `-u` flag) the first entry of each group. And the first entry for each group is determined by the sorting. I hope it's a bit better to understand now.

Comment: That's pretty cool! I am getting the correct output now. Thank you very much @fancyPants!!! :)